# RxSwift combine observable with conditional

Tags: conditional-statements, observable, rx-swift

I'm trying to combine observables and I want them to run in sequence (e.g., perform step 1, if some condition is met then perform step 2, if some condition is met then perform step 3). The only way I've found to do this is to add the conditions to each step, which I'm not a fan of:  Here's a sample of my current solution:

```swift
enum Status {
    case unknown, exists, missing
}

func refresh() -> Observable<Status> {
    return checkLocalStatus()
        .flatMapLatest { $0 == .exists ? Observable.just($0) : self.attemptRemoteStatusOverride() }
        .flatMapLatest { $0 == .exists ? Observable.just($0) : self.attemptRemoteStatusUpdate() }
}

private func checkLocalStatus() -> Observable<Status> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        // Regarding Maxim Volgin's comment, here I'm converting a closure to an 
        // observable... why not use Observable.create?
        self.cache.status { (status) in
            guard status != .exists else {
                observer.onNext(status) // .exists
                observer.onCompleted()
            }

            /* I don't want this condition to be here */
            if ignoreRemote {
                // status is !exists and we should ignore remote, throw error
                observer.onError(Errors.remoteDisabled)
            }

            observer.onNext(.missing)
            observer.onCompleted()
        }
    }
}

private func attemptRemoteStatusOverride() -> Observable<Status> {
    return remote.statusOverride()
}

private func attemptRemoteStatusUpdate() -> Observable<Status> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        // Regarding Maxim Volgin's comment, here I'm converting a closure to an 
        // observable... why not use Observable.create?
        self.remote.updateStatus { (status, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                observer.onError(error!)
            }
            observer.onNext(status)
            observer.onCompleted()
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to do something like:

```swift
func refresh() -> Observable<Status> {
    return checkLocalStatus()
        .if({ $0 != .exists && !ignoreRemote },
            then: { self.attemptRemoteStatusOverride() },
            else: { return $0 })
        .if({ $0 != .exists },
            then: { self.attemptRemoteStatusUpdate() },
            else: { return $0 })
}
```

or

```swift
func refresh() -> Observable<Status> {
    return checkLocalStatus()
        .flatMapLatest(if: { $0 != .exists && !ignoreRemote }) { self.attemptRemoteStatusOverride() }
        .flatMapLatest(if: { $0 != .exists }) { self.attemptRemoteStatusUpdate() }
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything like what I'm attempting, so I assume I'm going about this wrong. Does anyone have suggestions or alternatives on how to go about this route of combining observables? I've seen examples using `combineLatest` and returning some results based on the result of something else, but I want to perform each step only if a condition is met. `combineLatest` would perform each step (every time) and then I would return the result(s) of some steps based on the output of other steps. I also started looking into writing a custom operator, but can't figure a way to do it.

**Update:** I've changed to the following and plan to write a method to remove duplication:

```swift
func refresh() -> Observable<Status> {
    return checkLocalStatus()
        .flatMapLatest { status -> Observable<Status>
            guard status != .exists && !ignoreRemote else {
                return Observable.just(status)
            }
            return self.attemptRemoteStatusOverride()
        }
        .flatMapLatest { status -> Observable<Status>
            guard status != .exists && !ignoreRemote else {
                return Observable.just(status)
            }
            return self.attemptRemoteStatusUpdate()
        }
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should not be using ‘Observable.create()’ unless you are building a library/framework.

Secondly, your ‘Observable’ emits only one ‘onNext’ event, so why not use ‘Single’ instead of ‘Observable’?

Would you please show how you intend to use these observables? Because it seems like you are trying to solve a problem you should not be having in the first place.

Comment: Why is it a "general rule" to not use `Observable.create()`? I have service facades and I want to return observables instead of using closures. It seems to be a common pattern with RxSwift. Where can I read more about this rule? I didn't know about `Single`, so that's helpful.

Comment: basically, because it is more work. in simple cases such as yours, preferred solution is using '.just()' or '.from()'. for services facades, you are better off using '.switchEmpty()', '.retryError()', '.catchErrorJustReturn()' and my personal favourite '.switchLatest()'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need some version of flatMapLatest function with conditions? You can make some function that does what you want with the syntax you want:

```swift
extension Observable {

    func flatMapLatest(condition: @escaping (E) -> Bool, then: @escaping (E) -> Observable, otherwise: @escaping () -> Observable) -> Observable {
        let observable = self.shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()
        let observableCondition = observable.map({ condition($0) }).shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()
        let observableThen: Observable<E> = observableCondition
            .filter({ $0 })
            .withLatestFrom(observable)
            .flatMapLatest({ then($0) })
            .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()
        let observableOtherwise: Observable<E> = observableCondition
            .filter({ !$0 })
            .withLatestFrom(observable)
            .flatMapLatest({ _ in otherwise() })
            .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()
        return Observable<Observable<E>>
            .from([observableThen, observableOtherwise])
            .merge()
    }
}
```

and use it

```swift
func refresh() -> Observable<Status> {
    let condition = { (status: Status) -> Bool in
        return status == .exists
    }
    let then = { (status: Status) -> Observable<Status> in
        return Observable.just(status)
    }
    return checkLocalStatus()
        .flatMapLatest(condition: condition, then: then, otherwise: self.attemptRemoteStatusOverride)
        .flatMapLatest(condition: condition, then: then, otherwise: self.attemptRemoteStatusUpdate)
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, however, I want those private methods to do whatever they're supposed to do, so they can be called elsewhere. I want the conditional logic to remain in the `refresh` method. If `attemptRemoteStatusOverride` is called then it should attempt remote status override. I've updated my original question with something that works, I just didn't know if there was another way to combine observables conditionally.